# Constant "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" when importing javascript on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, three.js, parceljs

Fairly knew to utilizing parcel, but I am importing a series of javascript modules with:

```
import animate from "./animate";
```

these js files are inside a folder "js" at the root of my site.

Everything seems to import correctly when running it locally with

```
npm run dev
```

Again, everything works fine locally. Errors only occur when pushed to Github pages. Thanks for any help with the issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding “.js” at the end of the file name?

Comment: @Marquizzo Thanks for the response. Yes when I add ".js" it ends up giving me the error: "The requested module './animate.js' does not provide an export named 'animate'"